# Visual Studio 2015 Code Analysis with StyleCop Analyzers

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, code-analysis, stylecop

I am using Visual Studio 2015 with Code Analysis with the NuGet package StyleCop analyzers. When I run code Analysis I also get warnings about auto generated code from classes generated by entity framework or added service references.

The headers of my generated files contain

```
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
// <copyright company="SomeCompany" file="MyFile.cs">
// Copyright © Some Company, 2011
// </copyright>
// <auto-generated />
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

or

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

In my project I have the option "Suppress results from generated code" enabled

How can I exclude my generated code from code analysis?

Comment: A comment is certainly not good enough, it requires the [GeneratedCode] attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the comment of Hans Passant I added the following attribute to my generated classes by changing the text template of my entity framework model

[GeneratedCode("EntityModelCodeGenerator", "6.1.3")]

public partial class .... 
{
}

The classes are now skipped by code analysis